# PHP on Windows cannot write to a folder

Tags: php, windows, file

I'm running some PHPUnit scripts on my local machine using Laragon's PHP instance which is working fine, except a certain folder I cannot write files to which is important to a test.

Checking in Windows Explorer this keeps getting marked as Read Only, and I can't remove it for some reason. I can delete and recreate the folder many times and it causes no errors except in PHP.

The error in PHP is "Permission Denied"

Comment: If your file system is NTFS it'll have a full-fledged ACL system with users and groups. Right click on the folder and look at the "Security" tab.

Comment: I did try that and it seemingly did nothing. Reboot on a new day and AVG Anti-virus seems to have reared it's head revealing it was responsible... damn work laptops and not having full choice on software